# How to add something crawlable to JavaScript links in order to satisfy Google Lighthouse

Tags: javascript, links, paypal, lighthouse, tabbed-content

I'm doing some Google lighthouse analysis on my site and the tool is complaining about our "add to cart" links. We use a pre-fab PayPal cart system called Vibracart, which is great but is uses this blank `href` with JavaScript to show the cart. We've also have this old tab interface that I'm not sure is done optimally. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

JavaScript Links that need to be made crawlable:

This link is used to open an on-page cart overlay that works with our PayPal cart

```
<a href="" onclick="showCart(); return(false)">
```

These links are examples of links that just change the display property of some elements on the page to toggle between visible content.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="hideall();show('tab_1');">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="hideall();show('tab_2');">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="hideall();show('tab_3');">
```

Obviously the cart link has an empty `href`, so I may be able to do something about that by just adding an id or something. I'm open to suggestions. I could really use some input on better ways to handle the tabbed interface. None of these links open a new page & I'd rather the content did not shift as id does when you target an id but I'm open to anything.